# Newtonsoft JSON parsing into object

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio, class, json.net

My VB is a bit rusty but I need to parse a JSON string. I did it already in C# where I didn't have an issue. This is an old project and I'm using VS2008 for it.
This is my class:

```
Public Class ResponseMeta
    Private _type As String
    <JsonProperty("type")> _
    Public Property type() As String
        Get
            Return _type.ToString()
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _type = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _message As String
    <JsonProperty("message")> _
    Public Property message() As String
        Get
            Return _message
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _message = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _message_v1 As String
    <JsonProperty("message-v1")> _
    Public Property message_v1() As String
        Get
            Return _message_v1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _message_v1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _message_v2 As String
    <JsonProperty("message-v2")> _
    Public Property message_v2() As String
        Get
            Return _message_v2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _message_v2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _message_v3 As String
    <JsonProperty("message-v3")> _
    Public Property message_v3() As String
        Get
            Return _message_v3
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _message_v3 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _message_v4 As String
    <JsonProperty("message-v4")> _
    Public Property message_v4() As String
        Get
            Return _message_v4
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _message_v4 = value
        End Set
    End Property 
End Class
```

The code to deserialize is:

```
Dim test As String
test = "{""response-meta"":{""type"":""S"",""message"":"""",""Total No Of Records"":"""",""message-v1"":""1"",""message-v2"":"""",""message-v3"":"""",""message-v4"":""""}}"
Dim testcl As ResponseMeta
testcl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ResponseMeta)(test)
```

All properties of the object are set to `Nothing` and if I add watch, it says:

> type = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

I have now spent countless hours on this and Google doesn't found a hint or a clue of what might be getting wrong here.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Why do you need to use an unsupported version of Visual Studio to edit old code? VS 2017 should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON does not match up to what you are trying to parse it to.

You are missing a root object.

```
Public Class RootObject
    Private _root As ResponseMeta
    <JsonProperty("response-meta")> _
    Public Property ResponseMeta() As ResponseMeta
        Get
            Return _root 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ResponseMeta)
            _root = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

So based on the JSON you would need to deserialize to root object first then get the meta data

```
Dim root As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(test)
Dim testcl As ResponseMeta = root.ResponseMeta
```